# Drawing on Petrel map window

Tags: ocean, petrel

I'm working on a plug in for petrel in I require drawing lines, polygons on a petrel map window, can it be possible using mouse events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create a process that takes mouse button clicks in a map window and creates lines or polygons from the input picks provided (`MapPickedPoint`). The process could create a new polyline object in a folder in the Petrel input tree that would be updated with each pick, or you can create your own custom domain object that is updated with each point pick. If you create a custom domain object you will need to also provide the method to draw the object in the map window.